# How do I get a visual indication of where Selenium is clicking?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to sort posts on Facebook by most recent. When I click on "New activity" `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'New activity')]").click()` it behaves as expected, opening a dropdown box. When I attempt to click on "See most recent posts first", it throws a 'non iteractible error'. I believe it's parent is the clickable element, so I'm attempt to click on that. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'See most recent posts first')]").find_element_by_xpath('..').click()` This behaves as if I've clicked on a different bit of the webpage. I'd love to have a little visual hint of where Selenium is clicking to help debug this issue. If anyone had suggestions for other ways to solve this issue I'd be greatful.

Setup code:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()        

    # Use this code to create your own cookie file:
    # driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
    # time.sleep(60)
    # pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies() ,open("cookies.pkl","wb"))


    # Login using cookies bucs Facebooks login system is a pain to navigate in html. (Presumably to discourage
    # bots like me.)
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/backstagetheatrejobs/")
    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/backstagetheatrejobs/")

    time.sleep(1)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'New activity')]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'See most recent posts first')]").find_element_by_xpath('..').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'New activity')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'See most recent posts first')]").find_element_by_xpath('..').click()
```

do this with **Explicit wait** :

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'New activity')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'See most recent posts first')]"))).click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

or if you just want to grab visual coordinates, you can probably do like this  :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
new_activity_web_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'New activity')]")))
y_relative_coord = new_activity_web_element.location['y']
x_absolute_coord = new_activity_web_element.location['x']
```

Comment: While a nice suggestion, this does not answer the question "how to get visual indication of a click".